# multiple instances of a view

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone view - which when called presents a form

```
$('#add-offer').click(function() {
    console.log("Here");
    formView = new TB_BB.RequestFormView({model : new TB_BB.Request(), el : '#main-container'});
    formView.render();
});
```

The view looks like

```
TB_BB.RequestFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        this.template = $("#formTemplate"); 
        _.bindAll(this,"render");
    },
    events : {
        "submit #request-form" : "save",
    },
    render : function() {       
        $('#add-offer-button').hide();
        $(self.el).show();      
        var content = this.template.tmpl();
        $(this.el).html(content);
        return this;
    },
    save : function(event){
        console.log("Saved ");      
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I have found that every time the 
    submit #request-form

Event is triggered, it is triggered to EVERY instance of that view - however I thought it would be out of scope.

So for example if I on documentload call

```
$(function(){
    //create the router...  
    TB_BB.r = new TB_BB.Requests(TB_BB.initialData.requests);
    app = new TB_BB.Router();   
    Backbone.history.start();
    formView2 = new TB_BB.RequestFormView({model : new TB_BB.Request(), el : '#main-container'});
    formView3 = new TB_BB.RequestFormView({model : new TB_BB.Request(), el : '#main-container'});
    formView2.render();
});
```

And then I click the submit of the form, I see 'Saved' 3 times in the console rather than one? should that happen? can I only have one instance of a view?

Any help appreciated

Comment: i see two flaws, 1 you are using an ID in your selector, but if you render two views to the screen, you will have 2 elements with the same ID in the dom, thats not good, and second,  your selector is now looking for a submit button, with a childnode that has an ID request-form. i think you have to leave out the space between submit and #request-form

Comment: Shouldn't `$(self.el).show();` in your `render` method be `$(this.el).show();`? I don't see `self` defined anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have multiple instances of a view,
and they will be of a separate scope as long as they are working with different dom elements.

you, on the other hand, pass the dom element to the view, via the [`el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el) argument, so you specifically tell your 2 or 3 views that they need to manage the same element. thus they will both trigger on your submit button.

```
$(function(){
    //create the router...  
    ...

    // here you pass #main-container as the element for the view, 
    // so both these two views, will be handeling the same element. 
    // So, if some event is triggered within that scope, like a click on 
    // a submit button inside this scope, both the views will get the event triggered.
    formView2 = new TB_BB.RequestFormView({model : new TB_BB.Request(), el : '#main-container' });
    formView3 = new TB_BB.RequestFormView({model : new TB_BB.Request(), el : '#main-container' });

    ...
});
```

you can have multiple instances of a view, working separately, you can see examples of that, on the backbone [documentation's example section](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#examples)

one of the best known examples would be the TODO application ([source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html)) where all todo items are instances of the same todoView, each managing click events within their own scope.

Comment: Thanks - thats interesting that it is scoped to the dom rather than variable it was initialised too.

Have solved above, but found a similar issue, so I have a list of 'requests' and then a button to 'send a message', the send form I was loading in one dom selector (#message-content).  However similarly it sends multiple requests after each time I load a new 'message' into that selector.  So given I want to load the message box in the same dom element, how do I get round this?  The todo example doesn't have the issue as once a element is added its directly edited in its own unique dom.

Comment: it's actually pretty logic that it's scoped to the dom element because these events you're trying to use, are passed trough jquery, like this: $('selector', view-element-context);  so if your view element is the same, then your selector will result in the same elements being bound to. about your second issue, i'd just create a separate Q&A here on Stack overflow, with the code, me or someone else can help you alot further with proper code examples than doing it here in the comments